# Dynamically calculate batch_size for bulk_create in Django

Tags: mysql, django

```
(1153, "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes")
```

Is there a way, where I can calculate the `optimal batch_size`, to give it as argument while calling bulk_create.

PS: I am not allowed to change the max_allowed_packet